# multiples ids with same class issue

Tags: html, css, identifier

I'm trying to apply a hover action to multiple elements with different ids, but margin and background position don't change, but when I use the same code for each id it works fine, anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!!

```
<li id='gostou' class='menuacao' title="Gostou do Filme?">
     <a class='link' href="" target="_blank"></a>
</li>

<li id='assistir' class='menuacao' title="Gostou do Filme?">
     <a class='link' href="" target="_blank"></a>
</li>
```

the css looks like this

```
#gostou {
    background: transparent url('img/trailer.png');
    margin: 5px 2px;
}

#assistir {
    background: transparent url('img/tags.png');
    margin: 5px 2px;
}

.menuacao {
    background-position: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer; 
}

.menuacao:hover {
    margin: 5px -5px;
    background-position: -80px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```

Comment: what browser are you using for testing this?

Comment: chrome, firefox and safari!

Comment: and if I use ".menuacao:hover#gostou {...}" then it will work, but I cant' do it for multiple ids...

Comment: Works fine in my chrome... http://jsfiddle.net/6EYJV/

Comment: it still don't move left in my...

Answer (score 0):

You should separate multiple selectors with commas and repeat `:hover` for each selector, like this:

```
#gostou:hover, #assistir:hover {
    margin: 5px -5px;
    background-position: -80px;
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vovkss/reNcu/

Comment: thanks, i ended up using ".menuacao:hover#gostou, .menuacao:hover#assistir" because i plan to use jquery to change the menuacao class... Thanks again!

Comment: Small note, But I believe in IE7, :hover won't work on anything but an anchor tag.